# exclude IE7 from a piece of jQuery?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I seem to have a problem with some jQuery, and I can't figure out where I am going wrong so I just want to take ie7 out of the equation by excluding it, can this be done with jQuery?

Comment: I'd be surprised (kinda) if IE7 was the issue, jQuery is designed to work on all browsers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891472/ie7-kills-my-jquery-drop-down-on-main-navigation-menu/3891649#3891649

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need the detection inside a script(conditional comments are HTML-comments), you can detect it by checking some properties.

```
var ie7 = (document.all && !window.opera && window.XMLHttpRequest && typeof window.external.AddToFavoritesBar=='undefined') ? true : false;
var ie7mode = (document.all && !window.opera && window.XMLHttpRequest && !document.querySelectorAll) ? true : false;
```

inside a script you can use it like this:

```
if(!ie7mode)
{
  //this will be ignored in IE7 or higher versions running in IE7-mode
}  
if(!ie7)
{
  //this will be ignored in IE7 only
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/ :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about jQuery, but you could prevent the code from running using [Conditional Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx)